# API to track how often something on the page accessed (ex:URL, map, photos clicked)

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, google-analytics-api, bing-api

Good day!
I have this task to create an API that can access information on how often something on the page was accessed (either when URL or photo is clicked or how many times an item is searched in google/yahoo). i am thinking that maybe google already has an existing API that does this. Does anyone know how they do it? Or, can anyone show me how i can retrieve this information from any other sites (say, i will just input the URL of yahoo or facebook then retrieve a list of the most viewed page on that site? Is this possible?

I will appreciate your help asap. Thanks.

what i wanted to do is something similar to this one:
http://www.wordstream.com/adwords-keyword-tool

Answer (score 0):

http://www.alexa.com/ is about as close as it gets.

If you're able to monitor the traffic over a series of networks you can get a good idea for which sites are receiving the most traffic. Most tracking Google or ad providers use is through pixel tracking or through their tracking API.

Comment: what is this tracking API that they use? can you give me the API that i can use for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics lets you instrument a web page for how often that page is visited. I don't know about measuring the clicks of things that aren't web pages, though (such as a photo). That being said, you can easily implement something like this yourself. For measuring clicks, all you need is an onclick or onmousedown/ontouchdown handler that issues an AJAX request to an endpoint that you create for logging the clicks. For measuring how many times an image is loaded (including direct loads that bypass your website), you would need to create a URL handler for serving the image that also logs the load as a side-effect (though I would recommend not doing this, since logging in the image handler would make your image URL no longer cacheable).

Comment: the purpose of the API i am making is not to check on how many times a user clicks on a photo or link on our website. it is to retrieve information of the top searches made on another site. for instance, if i provide keyword like "hotels" and "google" i would retrieve the number of instances that hotel is searched in google search or how many times picture of hotel is clicked in google.

Comment: I see. In that case, you would use Google Analytics to instrument your page (I don't think there is a way to instrument a photo, though). You might also try using the Webmaster tools. Both the Webmaster tools and Google Analytics show the search terms (in aggregate) that led to the website.

Comment: tnx. i figured out google analytics require you to sign up before google can give you code fragment that can be integrated to a webpage code so that google can keep track of viewing frequency. it is limited to tracking my own site only but i can't get information bout how many times other sites or search topics are accessed over the net.